# Razor page does not contain definintion of Html helper class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am currently working on an MVC project. The project is working fine on another colleagues machine but I am having trouble with this project. It constantly gives errors with Html helper classes.

> "System.Web.WebPages.HtmlHelper does not contain a definition for 'TextboxFor' does not contain definition and no extension method 'TextBoxFor' accepting argument of type System.Web.WebPages.HtmlHelper could be found."

I have googled this problem but have not found any useful solution.
Here are some steps that I tried to solve this problem.

1. Clean solution and rebuild it.
2. removed `bin` and `obj` folder and rebuild the solution.
3. checked references in `web.config` files (both)
4. Added refrences in `web.config` like System.Web.Mvc etc..
5. Copied packages from other colleagues' machine.

*Note: I am using visual studio 2013 with MVC 5*

Comment: That's because it doesn't. The `TextboxFor()` method is in the `System.Web.Mvc.Html` namespace.

Comment: I have VS2013 as well and this is my Webconfig **in Views folder** (not the one at root level) https://www.dropbox.com/s/4myo9u4fkqxf0ms/web.config?dl=0 I have MVC version 5.0.0.0 (runtime v4.0.30319) and it works fine with TextBoxFor.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're missing the following in the `Web.Config` **in the views folder**:

/Views/Web.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />

      <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage"> // <-- this line and contents are important
        <namespaces>
          <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
          <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        </namespaces>
      </pages>

  </system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Views typically derive from `System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage` which is configured in the web.config.  Make sure the version above matches the version you need.